# Sharepoint Designer Workflow Booleans

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow

When using a Boolean variable in a SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflow is Yes/No suppose to synonymous with true/false?

My workflow uses the "Set Variable" action to set my boolean and then later tests to see if it is Yes or No.  However, the designer only shows yes/no options so I am not sure if this is setting it to true false properly.

I am confused because when testing the variable only yes/no options are again available and the test always allows me code to execute even when the variable is false.   I know the value is false on account of the "log to history" action which outputs the value of the variable.

Thanks

Comment: This is one of my biggest pet peeves about the platform, the inconsistancy of booleans at both the list level and in workflows.

Answer (score 1):

It is setting to True/False properly. I am using both SharePoint Designer and Visual Studio workflows to work with the same boolean variables, it matches: Yes/No in SPD equals true/false in VS.

This also works in List View's filters. E.g. if you want view to show only items with True set, it works with "Yes" as filter value.

Answer (score 0):

I have to test this again to be sure, but I believe you want to use 1 and 0, not true and false.

I am also pretty sure anything that isn't 1/0 is considered true, so the string "true" and the string "false" are both 1.